# How delete not initialized google function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

How i can delete this function from gcloud API, or google console. I get this error after my try create function, and now I can't delete it. For create function I used google console. Error message say me that not initialize region. But in screen i see region us-central1. My try delete this function return unknown error. Maybe anybody knows another way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to delete in CLI/SDK/Cloud Shell using `gcloud` command :

- `gcloud functions delete function-name`

If you still encountered the error, the possible workaround I suggest, try to **disable** and **enable** again the **Cloud Function API** then redeploy, if it is successful then delete or continue to use it.

Please note you cannot disable the **Cloud Function API**, if there's a working Cloud Function deployed. You can disable and enable the **Cloud Function API** by doing the gcloud command below:

- `gcloud services disable cloudfunctions.googleapis.com`
- `gcloud services enable cloudfunctions.googleapis.com`

If the workaround doesn't work, I'll recommend to contact the Google Cloud Platform Support or create a [**Public Tracker Issue**](https://issuetracker.google.com) to inspect the action id in the error.

### UPDATE :

Please visit the [Google Cloud dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) see the yellow banner at the top, it said that **`"10% of Cloud Functions deployments are failing in us-central1"`**. According to the error of Cloud Function and location, it looks like you are one of the affected users. If there is no yellow banner, it should be completely fixed.